# QGIS Map Composer goes blank, outputs corrupt PDF

Tags: qgis, cartography, print-composer, pdf, png

I am using 64bit 2.10.1-Pisa on Windows 10.

When I set up my composer to print, everything looks fine until I try to print or export. The composer goes completely blank and outputs a corrupted PDF using the Export to PDF function. The PDF file won't even open.

I had the same result exporting to PNG.

When I try to use the PDF document printer instead of exporting, QGIS stops responding indefinitely.

Comment: Did you use Osgeo4W installer or standalone installer?

Comment: Can you provide some additional details. Does it fail for a specific document or even for a simple composer with no map items and only text elements and graphics?
Does the same documents outputs correctly under previous version or under a different OS (if you can check)

Comment: After some testing it seems to be connected to if I have the OpenStreetMap-layer visible or not, works well if OSM is hidden..!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the OpenLayers plugin, don't!

It's got all sorts of issues with print composer and exporting maps.

Use "quick map services" plugin instead.