# Every time I export a new print composer (either image, svg, or PDF) in QGIS 2.18.1, I lose my composer

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer, qgis-2.18

As the title suggests, whenever I attempt to make a new print composer (in either windows or Linux, I have tried both) with my map, it goes blank and the file is not exported.

When I attempt to export as a PDF, I get the message "Advanced composition effects such as blend modes or vector layer transparency are enabled in this project, which cannot be printed as vectors. Printing as a raster is recommended." Would this prevent my ability to make a PDF from the print composer?

If so, how can I rectify this?

Since I have a low reputation, if you need pictures I can provide them in the comments.

Comment: Yes, add those images please.

Comment: http://imgur.com/tSlHovi http://imgur.com/IjJq6UK http://imgur.com/4A101wX

Comment: Just in case you are using OpenLayers plugin; [QGIS Map Composer goes blank, outputs corrupt PDF](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167233/qgis-map-composer-goes-blank-outputs-corrupt-pdf)

Comment: Ah yes, I am I will follow the advice and use the Quick Map Services. Thank you!